# Can't connect 587 port from external postfix/dovercot using tls

Tags: iptables, smtp, postfix, dovecot

Can't connect to the smtp port 567

I built mail server postfix+dovecot.

`openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect localhost:587`

This works and be able to send email manually.

`openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.example.com:587`

shows this error

```
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=61
```

What I have checked are netstat, iptables.

Both look work well for 587 submission.

netstat -anutp

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58592         127.0.0.1:587           ESTABLISHED 2793/openssl    
tcp        0    388 133.242.184.252:22      210.149.252.243:46415   ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           127.0.0.1:58592         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 133.242.184.252:123     0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                -
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:3000
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Is there any other points I should check???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that iptables rules are read *top to bottom.* When you add a rule with `-A` it's appended at the end (or after the given number), when you use `-I` it is inserted in front.

Now you basically have:

1. accept ICMP, HTTP, SSH, ...
2. reject *everything*
3. accept SMTP, POP3

So you need to move the "accept SMTP..." rules *above* the blanket reject.

You can delete them and re-add by manually specifying the position:

```
     iptables -A INPUT 7 -p tcp ...
(or) iptables -I INPUT 8 -p tcp ...
```

(Use `iptables -L --line` to see rule numbers.)

Alternatively, edit the full list at once – and just swap the lines around:

```
iptables-save > rules.txt
nano rules.txt
iptables-restore < rules.txt
```

---

Side notes:

- In the future, it might be better if you posted the rules using `iptables -S` or even `iptables-save`; it's a bit easier to scan than the heavily-reformatted `-L` output. (Or maybe both.)
- Dovecot only speaks POP/IMAP/LMTP, but not SMTP. Your SMTP server is Postfix.
- When using `netstat` with the `-p` option, you should run the command as root, otherwise it won't actually display any of the process information.

Comment: Thanks for your great explaination. I was not familliar with iptables. also thank you for your advice about POP/IMAP , netstat. It's quite helpful! My problem was of course solved

Answer (score 1):

Iptables sequentially try to match your rules in the order they appear.
In your case (**as said in comments, please provide the result of `iptables -S` commands, as we lack information with `iptables -L` like the matching interface**)

1. if packets match `state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` on interface **?**, they are accepted and no more match on these packets is done ;
2. else, if packets match `icmp` on interface **?** they are accepted, and no more match on these packets is done;
3. else, iptables accept all packets on interface **?**
4. ....

So given we don't know on which interface are done the rules, I think that your only REJECT rule (on INPUT table) is matched on the same interface than you `tcp dpt:smtp` rule. As your REJECT rule is matched **before** your snmp rule, the last is never matched.

**EDIT** too long to write the post ...

Comment: THanks as you mentioned the order was problem. I need to learn about iptables more.